# jquery Autocomplete not working in Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I want autocomplete feature on bootstrap modal. JQuery autocomplete is working fine on simple page, but in case of modal autocomplete not working. I am not able to solve this problem. I don't know how to solve this. I am new in jQuery. Any body please help. I attached my code snippet.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() 
       {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:"http://localhost:8080/ITCBillDesk/retrievePaymentPurposeDesc"
            }).then(function(data) 
            {
               console.log(data);
               $("#tags").autocomplete(
                {
                  source: data
                });
            });
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="ui-widget">
                        <label for="tags">Tags: </label> <input id="tags">
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see when `console.log(data);` is executed?

Comment: yes that is executed for modal also that is data is printed on console.

Comment: Paste the result you see on the console. Autocomplete requires either an array of primitives or an array of name-id objects.

Comment: [
  "BOARDING CHARGE",
  "FINE",
  "LATE FEE",
  "BOARDING\n CHARGE",
  "EXAM.FEES",
  "DONATION ",
  "GOVERMENT FEES",
  "INSTITUTE FEES",
  "INSTITUTE\n FEES",
  "GOVT. FEES",
  "Inst.Fees ",
  "Inst.Fees\n ",
  "Late Fine",
  "sale proceeds",
  "TUITION FEE PHYSICS",
  "Tution Fees",
  "sale proceeds of wastes food",
  "Computer Course Fees",
  "SALE PROCEEDS OF COAL DUST",
  "GOVERMENT FEES FOR XII",
  "INSTITUTE  FEES FOR XII",
  "BOARDING CHARGE FOR XII"
]

Comment: My Autocomplete feature is working fine on simple page not working for modal only #zorgoz

Comment: Try fetching the data and updating the autocomplete on "modal.bs.shown" instead of page ready.

Comment: Thanks @zorgoZ its working.

Answer (score 12):

in modal-body add class ui-front

```
<div class="modal-body ui-front"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
       {
          $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function ()
           {
            $.ajax(
            {
               url:"http://localhost:8080/ITCBillDesk/retrievePaymentPurposeDesc"
            }).then(function(data) 
            {
               console.log(data);
               $("#testid").autocomplete(
                {
                 source:data
                });
            });
                   });     
        });
```